# Connecting three monitors with digital cables

Tags: graphics-cards, multiple-monitors

I have the 3 [BenQ GW2270](http://www.benq.co.uk/product/monitor/gw2270/) monitors and a [Gigabyte Z87-HD3 Intel Z87](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z87-HD3-rev-1x) Motherboard.

I want to be able to connect all three monitors to a digital port, but my motherboard only has 1 X HDMI, 1 X DVI and 1 X VGA. I notice most of the motherboards and graphics cards I've looked at have three display ports but only 2 are digital. I have them connected to my motherboard using the three different connection types.

How can I get around this, other than spending quite a lot on a new motherboard or high spec graphics card? I only use my PC for general usage and no gaming. The display of these monitors is 1920 X 1080 so nothing intense. The reason for this is so that I have a consistent picture across all three monitors.

Could I get two graphics cards with one or two digital ports on each? Maybe something like [this](https://www.ebuyer.com/704283-gigabyte-r5-230-1gb-ddr3-vga-dual-link-dvi-hdmi-pci-e-graphics-gv-r523d3-1gl)

What about a DMS graphics card which would use this kind of [splitter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-DMS-59-Dual-DVI/dp/B0017K6BBO)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I may ask, what is the need? What's not good enough with the VGA?

Comment: The display is much slower to react when turning on compared to the other screens.

Answer (score 1):

There are motherboards that have three digital video outs. For example, the [Asus Z97-A](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/Z97A/) has one DisplayPort, HDMI, DVI, and VGA connector, and supports [three displays simultaneously.](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000025672/graphics-drivers.html)

Alternatively, you could get a graphics card that has three digital outs. [Something as cheap as an HD 5750](https://us.bidvoy.net/hd_5750/27386) should fulfill the requirement without requiring any extra power from your PSU. I'd recommend just browsing eBay looking for something in the Radeon HD 5000-7000 series or GeForce 400-700 series.

One final option: you could use an [MST hub on an enabled DisplayPort port/GPU/OS](https://blog.startech.com/post/connecting-multiple-monitors-multi-stream-transport-and-what-it-means-for-you/) to split a single DisplayPort signal into multiple DisplayPort outs and connect each to a given monitor, but because of the high cost of this method, I won't detail it.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a cheap external videcard with 1 digital Out and then using it together with your integrated motherboard's video. But previously you need to check that your motherboard's BIOS supports this function - you can find extra information [there](https://superuser.com/questions/737546/can-i-use-both-my-internal-and-external-graphics-card-in-same-system) . It works well in Windows 10. I used this way in other case: my external card has only digital outputs, but I need to plug third monitor with VGA input only.

Comment: AFAIK neither current gen Intel or AMD CPUs support this feature.

Comment: @JMY1000 I hope, this video helps you to believe that it works - https://youtu.be/0BoktTdEZFE

Comment: Not his motherboard or a current gen processor unfortunately, I wouldn't count on this feature.